# "How to apply 'Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)' Code to all rows in worksheet"

Tags: vba

"I am trying to run `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` for E7:E17 to achive below (For Example)

```
If E7 = Yes then F7="Reject", G7=H7, I7=2*10, 
   E7 = No then F7="Pass", G7=H7*5, I7=2,
   .
   .
If E17 = = Yes the F17="Type", G7=H17, I17=2*10,
   E17 = No then F17="Pass", G17=H17*5, I17=2,
```

I tried like righting separate code for each row, code works for only 7 rows after that error is coming (Procedure is too Long)

Worksheet_Change code:-

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E7:E17")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Range("E7:E17")
      Case "NO": MacroNoE7
      Case "YES": MacroYesE7
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Example of VBA Code to run in rows E7:E17:-

```
Sub MacroYesE7()

Sheets("Data").Range("E162").Copy
Sheets("Data").Range("L7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Data").Range("L7") = ""
Sheets("Data").Range("M7") = ""

End Sub

Sub MacroNoE7()

Range("L7").Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
End With

Sheets("Data").Range("L7") = "NA"
Sheets("Data").Range("M7") = "NA"

End Sub
```

Error Message:- Procedure is too long

Comment: Not sure what you're doing, but you might need a function or sub with arguments which means you only need 2 procedures.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. Pass Target (the changed cell) to each of the subs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E7:E17")) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
      Case "NO": MacroNo (Target)
      Case "YES": MacroYes (Target)
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub MacroYes(r As Range)

Sheets("Data").Range("E162").Copy
Sheets("Data").Range("L" & r.Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Data").Range("L" & r.Row).Resize(, 2).ClearContents

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub MacroNo(r As Range)

Range("L" & r.Row).Validation.Delete

Sheets("Data").Range("L" & r.Row).Resize(, 2).Value = "NA"

End Sub
```